# how to set locks on tables in jdbc using java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I have a small Java Web application, which has a form which accepts name from front-end and stores the same name in three different tables.I have primary key autogenerated  when inserting the front-end data to the table. I have used Oracle database to store the data.The problem is when the same application is run on two different machines and at the same point of time input is provided in front-end on two different machines and submitted at same time, it is creating conflicts i.e  user1's data is assigned to user2 and similarly user2's data is assigned to user1. Before inserting data to table, I would drop all three tables and recreate all three tables. The first primary key that gets generated ,and inserted to table along with front-end input should be same for all three table's.  All I need is when one user enters his data at the front-end and until that users data is stored in database successfully second user's must not be able to store data i.e the table should be locked for second user until the first user's data gets stored.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing how you are accessing the data, but it sounds like you are not using transactions in your code. Post some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: Read through : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: I am using simple JDBC technique to insert data into Table.